# Проблемы с мутацией в таблице БД ORACLE SQL Error: ORA-04091

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle, триггер

Я делаю БД с таблицей товаров и группой товаров. Проблема возникает с триггером **UPDATE_GROUP_C_RETAIL**. Мне нужно обновлять сводную стоимость при изменении входной стоимости или количества товаров. Когда я что-то пытаюсь вставить в таблицу товаров, возникает следующая ошибка:

> **SQL Error: ORA-04091: таблица USER1.PRODUCT изменяется, триггер/функция может не заметить это**

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
INSERT INTO PRODUCT (NAME, GROUP_ID,ENTRY_PRICE, COUNT)
VALUES ('Телевизор Philips',1, 12000,5)
Error at Command Line : 1 Column : 9
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-04091: таблица USER1.PRODUCT изменяется, триггер/функция может не заметить это
ORA-06512: на  "USER1.UPDATE_GROUP_C_RETAIL", line 8
ORA-04088: ошибка во время выполнения триггера 'USER1.UPDATE_GROUP_C_RETAIL'
04091. 00000 -  "table %s.%s is mutating, trigger/function may not see it"
*Cause:    A trigger (or a user defined plsql function that is referenced in
           this statement) attempted to look at (or modify) a table that was
           in the middle of being modified by the statement which fired it.
*Action:   Rewrite the trigger (or function) so it does not read that table.
```

Только недавно начал изучать БД ORACLE. Не могу понять, в чем дело. В чем причина проблемы и как ее пофиксить?
Полный код со всеми триггерами:

```
  CREATE TABLE "USER1"."PRODUCT" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER(*,0) DEFAULT "USER1"."PRODUCT_SEQUENCE"."NEXTVAL" NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "NAME" VARCHAR2(80 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "GROUP_ID" NUMBER(*,0) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "ENTRY_PRICE" NUMBER DEFAULT 0, 
    "RETAIL_PRICE" NUMBER DEFAULT 0, 
    "COUNT" NUMBER(*,0) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "PRODUCT_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS"  ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "PRODUCT_FK1" FOREIGN KEY ("GROUP_ID")
      REFERENCES "USER1"."PRODUCT_GROUP" ("ID") ENABLE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ;

CREATE OR REPLACE NONEDITIONABLE TRIGGER "USER1"."UPDATE_GROUP_COUNT_DELETE" 
BEFORE DELETE ON product
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  -- Уменьшаем "count" в группе товаров на значение "count" удаляемого товара
  UPDATE product_group
  SET count = count - :OLD.count
  WHERE id = :OLD.group_id;
END;
/
ALTER TRIGGER "USER1"."UPDATE_GROUP_COUNT_DELETE" ENABLE;

CREATE OR REPLACE NONEDITIONABLE TRIGGER "USER1"."UPDATE_GROUP_COUNT" 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON product
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  -- Обновляем "COUNT" в группе товаров внутри блока транзакции
  UPDATE product_group  SET count = count+:new.count WHERE id = :NEW.group_id;
  
END;
/
ALTER TRIGGER "USER1"."UPDATE_GROUP_COUNT" ENABLE;

CREATE OR REPLACE NONEDITIONABLE TRIGGER "USER1"."UPDATE_RETAIL_PRICE" 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON product
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE
    v_markup product_group.markup%TYPE;
  BEGIN
    -- Получаем наценку на группу товара
    SELECT markup
    INTO v_markup
    FROM product_group
    WHERE id = :NEW.group_id;

    -- Вычисляем розничную цену
    :NEW.retail_price := :NEW.entry_price * (1 + v_markup);
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      -- Если группа товара не найдена
      :NEW.retail_price := 0;
  END;
END;
/
ALTER TRIGGER "USER1"."UPDATE_RETAIL_PRICE" ENABLE;

CREATE OR REPLACE NONEDITIONABLE TRIGGER "USER1"."UPDATE_GROUP_C_RETAIL" 
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON product
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  v_group_id NUMBER;
BEGIN
  -- Получаем идентификатор группы товаров для текущего товара
  v_group_id := :NEW.group_id;

  -- Обновляем "сводную стоимость" в группе товаров
  UPDATE product_group
  SET c_retail = (
    SELECT SUM(entry_price * count)
    FROM product
    WHERE group_id = v_group_id
  )
  WHERE id = v_group_id;
END;
/
ALTER TRIGGER "USER1"."UPDATE_GROUP_C_RETAIL" ENABLE;


  CREATE TABLE "USER1"."PRODUCT_GROUP" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER(*,0) DEFAULT "USER1"."GROUP_SEQUENCE"."NEXTVAL" NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "NAME" VARCHAR2(80 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "COUNT" NUMBER(*,0) DEFAULT 0, 
    "C_RETAIL" NUMBER DEFAULT 0, 
    "MARKUP" NUMBER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "PRODUCT_GROUP_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS"  ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "PRODUCT_GROUP_CHK1" CHECK (markup >= 0 AND markup <= 1
) ENABLE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ;

CREATE OR REPLACE NONEDITIONABLE TRIGGER "USER1"."UPDATE_RETAIL_PRICES" 
AFTER UPDATE OF MARKUP ON product_group
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  -- Обновляем розничные цены в таблице "Товары" для соответствующей группы
  UPDATE product
  SET retail_price = entry_price * (1 + :NEW.markup)
  WHERE group_id = :NEW.id;

END;
/
ALTER TRIGGER "USER1"."UPDATE_RETAIL_PRICES" ENABLE;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ORACLE не любит, когда совершаются действия над таблицей, на которой работает триггер.

Можно переписать тригер следующим образом, что бы не считать всю сумму по таблице каждый раз(если таблица будет большой, подсчет суммы по группе может занимать значительное время). При изменении записи, отнимаем старое значение и добавляем новое, при добавлении, просто добавляем новое:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE NONEDITIONABLE TRIGGER "USER1"."UPDATE_GROUP_C_RETAIL" 
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON product
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  -- Если обновление, иначе это добавление
  IF UPDATING THEN
    UPDATE product_group
    set c_retail = c_retail - :OLD.entry_price + :NEW.entry_price
    where group_id = :NEW.group_id;
  ELSE
    UPDATE product_group
    set c_retail = c_retail + :NEW.entry_price
    where group_id = :NEW.group_id;
  ELSE
  END IF;
  
END;
/
```

Так же рекомендую объединить триггеры **UPDATE_GROUP_COUNT** и **UPDATE_RETAIL_PRICE** в один, т.к. они вызываются по одному и тому же событию **BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON product**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE NONEDITIONABLE TRIGGER "USER1"."UPDATE_RETAIL_PRICE" 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON product
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE
    v_markup product_group.markup%TYPE;
  BEGIN
    -- Получаем наценку на группу товара
    BEGIN
        SELECT markup
        INTO v_markup
        FROM product_group
        WHERE id = :NEW.group_id;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
          -- Если группа товара не найдена
          :NEW.retail_price := 0;
    END;
    -- Вычисляем розничную цену
    :NEW.retail_price := :NEW.entry_price * (1 + v_markup);
    
    IF UPDATING THEN
      -- Обновляем "COUNT", он изменился
      UPDATE product_group 
      SET count = count + :new.count - :OLD.count 
      WHERE id = :NEW.group_id;
    ELSE
      -- Добавляем COUNT
      UPDATE product_group 
      SET count = count + :new.count 
      WHERE id = :NEW.group_id;
    END IF;

  END;
END;
/
```

> Старайтесь не называть поля таблиц зарезервированными словами, такими как COUNT, ID, SUM и т.д., потом могут быть сложности с доступом к ним.